# Gradient over storyboard in Watchkit/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit

I have a design for an apple watch app that consists of a table with five rows. I want to have a gradient that is overlain on top of the screen so that the screen gets darker further down the screen

The rows need to be the same colour so that when you scroll up then obviously they scroll 'above' the gradient

This should hopefully explain what I mean:
[image]

Is there a way of doing this in xcode or using swift?

Thanks!

Comment: There is currently no way to layer views in watchKit so I don't think this would be possible. At least, I can't think of any....

Comment: I've achieve a similar effect by setting the color of each row's `group` and incrementing it for each row. There is no background color but as the rows move then the color of the whole screen appears to move along the gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as rmp mentioned in the comment, there is no way to accomplish this in the current version of WatchKit. The only "layering" that is possible is by setting the background image of a `WKInterfaceGroup` that contains other image elements that appear "on top." In this case, however, you'd need an image above the `WKInterfaceTable`, and that functionality isn't available.

While you might think that you could alter the cell background colors as the table scrolls to achieve a similar effect, you can't determine the scroll location of a `WKInterfaceTable`, so there's no way to do this either.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

**Setting *Gradient Background* on *WKInterfaceGroup***

First, create this UImage class:

```
class UIGradientImage: UIImage {
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

convenience init?(size: CGSize, colors: [CGColor], locations: [CGFloat]) {
    let colors = colors as CFArray
    guard let grad = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors, locations: locations) else {return nil}
    self.init(size: size, gradient: grad)
}

convenience init?(size: CGSize, gradient: CGGradient) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let ref = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    ref?.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint.zero, end: CGPoint.init(x: size.width, y: size.height), options: [.drawsBeforeStartLocation, .drawsAfterEndLocation] )
    if let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.cgImage {
        self.init(cgImage: img)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    } else {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return nil
    }
}

override init(cgImage: CGImage) {
    super.init(cgImage: cgImage)
}

override init(cgImage: CGImage, scale: CGFloat, orientation: UIImageOrientation) {
    super.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: orientation)
}

required convenience init(imageLiteralResourceName name: String) {
    fatalError("init(imageLiteralResourceName:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Then, add a **WKInterfaceGroup** to your interface and set its background image to a new **UIGradientImage**:

```
    let size = self.contentFrame.size
    self.myGroup.setBackgroundImage(UIGradientImage(size: size, colors: [UIColor.cyan.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor], locations: [0, 1]))
```

Good luck!

Comment: i get two errors: 
- Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported
- 'required' initializer 'init(imageLiteralResourceName:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UIImage'